# What should I use instead of sequence in order to avoid gaps?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm developing a system that allows to organise paper documents in folders. When folder is full, user hits 'New folder' button. This action calls `nextval()` of sequence of folders.

Here is how this table of documents looks like:

```
IDDOC FOLDER PARTNER USER
1     1      1341    56
....
700   2      4532    56
```

The only problem is that gaps between folder numbers from sequence are pretty big.

Folder numbers I have now: `69, 89, 109, 129, 149, 169, 209`.

What should I use instead of sequence to avoid it?

Comment: Hi ,you can change increment by value of sequence by 1 or 2 whatever you required. Also you can use row_number or dense_rank function.

Comment: Use sequence with no cache parameter, it will decrease the gaps. Hope you using value increment sequence by 1 or 2 only as suggested by @TahreemSaeed

Comment: Why bother? An id is just an id, and as long as it's unique it's fine.

Comment: @tahreem-saeed, Yes, I use increment by 1

Comment: @jarlh I agree with you, but folder number is used in offline archive

Comment: @mansi-raval, Thanks fo NOCHACHE. I'm going to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main purpose of sequences is to provide a source of **guaranteed** unique identifiers. These are technical keys and generally speaking their actual value should be irrelevant. I mean - do you even need to show the folder number to the user?

If you're that bothered use NOCACHE. That will minimise the gaps you're seeing, and as long as you don't create folders very often you won't notice the performance hit from not caching a slack handful of numbers. You still may get gaps, if a transaction is rolled back or fails for any other reason but they should be infrequent; if they're not you have bigger things to worry about than the numbering of your folders!

Other ways of generating a monotonically incrementing series are either cumbersome to implement (triggers over code control tables) or not guaranteed to be unique (using `max(id)+1` in a trigger). If you want to use a code control table - that is a table which specifically tracks the last assigned folder ID - you should have a look [at a previous answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43673018/146325_) which should how to do implement one. The one advantage of a code control table is that we can maintain counts with a group. So you could have a run of folder ids for each user, and increment them independently.

Comment: Thankh you! I will try NOCHACHE. Folder number is used to store paper documents in archive. Archive employee can easily find a right document when he or she knows a folder number. Small gaps would be ok in this case.

Comment: @APC The code control table solution you linked to is very nice, but not guaranteed to be gapless for the same reasons a sequence is not gapless: namely, there is no guarantee that the caller puts the returned ID into the table and commits it without errors.  I think gapless is usually a poor requirement and one that is often dropped when people realize its high technical costs and low business value.  Still, I thought maybe it was worth mentioning since this question was specifically about gapless sequences.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak I get what you're telling! Really, I do. The technical costs are huge and business value very low... but, what can one do when the Government requires that there can't be any gaps in a sequence and you can't generate it on the fly as the "sequence number" is part of the record's "hash"? What a predicament I must face :-)

Comment: @Loudenvier In that case, see the answer by LoztInSpace here.  You need to serialize everything.  If you start a transaction, get determine it will be, say, txn #100 in your gapless sequence, the next transaction cannot start until the first one finishes.  Because if the first one rolls back, the second one must be txn #100, and we cannot know that until the first one commits (or rolls back).

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak I did some of this. I've segregated it to a centralized, non-load-balanced, single-instance endpoint and control insertion/sequence generation with thread locks. Not the best solution as throughput for this specific table now is much lower, but the rest of the database don't suffer any performance hit.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak To guarantee "gaplessness" (e.g., if an outside process adds anything out of order in the table) I also periodically inspect for gaps using code adapted from here: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/gaps-islands-sql-server-data/   and if found it will trigger a periodic warning until "someone" fixes it :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can't without forcing your database to be serializable.  That will mean very poor throughput due to no parallel updates, i.e. every transaction will have to wait for the one before it (to see if the number is used).  Also, no rollbacks so you'll have to select from a counter table (also bad).

You are best to ignore the gaps.  If you cannot do that you can do one of two things.

1) Assign the sequence number then periodically go back and fill in the gaps with dummy records.

2) Keep doing what you do and also have an unassigned "real" sequence number that you periodically fill in after the event when all your transactions are committed.

Generally though, the "no gap" requirement is bogus.

Comment: My experience with these kind of identifiers is that serialization is rarely an issue. Users probably create a folder once a day or once a week; torrents of concurrent updates is just not something that happens.

Comment: Perhaps in this case it's ok but as a general pattern it's not a good option.

Answer (score 1):

As @APC says sequences ensure uniqueness.

If you want to have "serial numbering" for the folder columns, then don't use a sequence. You can store the "last used folder value" on a separate table, and use it manually to get a new number each time you need one. Make sure you raise the transaction level to `SERIALIZABLE` when you perform these updates.